# indent grouped cells like iphone contacts

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I'd like to have a gruped table where the first section has 2 row and 1 imageview like contacts app.

something like this: [screeshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aNFJl.png)

How can I do that?

Thanks,
Max

Answer (score 3):

The other solutions require you to create your own background images and use two tableviews which is not convenient. What I did was subclass UITableViewCell and indented the background views as such:

```
#define INDENT_WIDTH 84

...

- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    //Indent the background views.
    CGRect frame = self.backgroundView.frame;
    frame.origin.x = frame.origin.x + INDENT_WIDTH;
    frame.size.width = frame.size.width - INDENT_WIDTH;
    self.backgroundView.frame = frame;
    self.selectedBackgroundView.frame = frame;

   //Also indent the UIImageview that contains like a shadow image over the backgroundviews (in grouped tableview style only).
   for (UIView *subview in self.subviews) {
        if ([subview isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]]) {
            CGRect frame = subview.frame;
            frame.origin.x = frame.origin.x + INDENT_WIDTH;
            frame.size.width = frame.size.width - INDENT_WIDTH;
            subview.frame = frame;
        }
   }
}
```

Since the content view has a transparent background color you can place a UIImageView (e.g on your storyboard cell prototype) on the left side and you should get the same effect as the "Add Contact" view in the Contacts App.

Comment: I still saw a separator line to the left of the indented cells, but then realized it was in the UITableView: [tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];

Answer (score 1):

Please see this question:

[Is it possible to adjust the width of a UITableViewCell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043099/is-it-possible-to-adjust-the-width-of-a-uitableviewcell)

It seems there's no convenient way to actually reduce the width of a cell (or cell group).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the same in the screenshot by:

(1) A parent view controller with a view having a background color similar to that of a UITableViewStyleGrouped.

(2) Add the photo on a UIImageView which would be a subView to (1)

(3) Add the UITableView (Grouped Style) on the right side again as a subview to (1)

Set the frames of both subviews properly and accordingly for the layout in the screenshot and use delegation to "logically connect" both subviews.

Edit: The background color can be achieved using [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:(UIImage *)image]. Just crop the background from any sample app on the iphone simulator.

Comment: This doesn't achieve the effect he wants -- he wants the subsequent table sections to be full width.

Comment: I once had the need for two subviews to scroll in sync with each other. Left and right. You can achieve that as well easily via delegation. There are numerous posts on SO which describe that.

Comment: Can't believe there's no a simple way to call indentation even when you're not in editing mode. anyway.... I know the way, lot of work to do subclassing the world ;)